# Is it normal that aria-live (polite) doesn't work on table caption in Safari?

Tags: html, safari, accessibility, voiceover, aria-live

If I place the `aria-live` attribute in a table caption like this:

```
    <table>
        <caption aria-live="polite"></caption>
        ...
    </table>
```

And then update the caption's `textContent` VoiceOver (macOS) in Safari (14.0.3) doesn't read the caption. It works with VoiceOver in Chrome. I also tried to put a `span` inside the `caption` and many many variations on this theme (moving the `aria-live` attribute, updating the `innerHTML`, etc.). But the moment the change is inside the `caption`, Safari will not read the change.

Is anyone have an idea how to make this works?

Here's a fiddle that demonstrate the problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/06phkrL8/

Comment: I assume in the real world you haven't missed a closing double quote on `aria-live="polite`? Can you put a fiddle together that works in Chrome but not in Safari?

Comment: Fixed missing quote (thanks!) and added a fiddle. Strangely Chrome repeat the text two times in this fiddle. It was not doing that in my local tests.

Comment: For the moment I fix it by replacing the `<caption>` by a `<p>` outside of the table and using `aria-describedby`on the table to associate the `<p>` as the caption.